Trouble when compiling rolling_sharpe_ratio in VectorBT
Im just trying to run vectorbt to test out some of it's functions, in this case the rolling_sharpe, but I keep getting this error, does anyone know to solve this problem?
File "/Users/datwiththed/Desktop/Trading algorithm/Pyrobot/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    rolling_sharpe = vbt.returns.nb.rolling_sharpe_ratio_nb(returns.to_numpy(), window=3, minp=3, risk_free=0, ann_factor=252, ddof=1)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/datwiththed/Desktop/Trading algorithm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 423, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/Users/datwiththed/Desktop/Trading algorithm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 364, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
tuple index out of range
During: typing of static-get-item at /Users/datwiththed/Desktop/Trading algorithm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/vectorbt/generic/nb.py (1084)

File "../.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/vectorbt/generic/nb.py", line 1084:
def rolling_apply_nb(a: tp.Array2d, window: int, minp: tp.Optional[int],
    <source elided>
    nancnt_arr = np.empty((a.shape[0],), dtype=np.int_)
    for col in range(a.shape[1]):
    ^

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function rolling_apply_nb at 0x12b358d60>))
During: typing of call at /Users/datwiththed/Desktop/Trading algorithm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/vectorbt/returns/nb.py (370)

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function rolling_apply_nb at 0x12b358d60>))
During: typing of call at /Users/datwiththed/Desktop/Trading algorithm/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/vectorbt/returns/nb.py (370)


File "../.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/vectorbt/returns/nb.py", line 370:
    def _apply_func_nb(i, col, _returns, _ann_factor, _risk_free, _ddof):
        <source elided>

    return generic_nb.rolling_apply_nb(
    ^

Here is my code
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import vectorbt as vbt

returns = pd.Series([0.01, 0.02, -0.01, 0.03, -0.02, 0.01, 0.005, 0.015])

rolling_sharpe = vbt.returns.nb.rolling_sharpe_ratio_nb(returns.to_numpy(), window=3, minp=3, risk_free=0, ann_factor=252, ddof=1)

rolling_sharpe_series = pd.Series(rolling_sharpe, index=returns.index)
print(rolling_sharpe_series)

after asking gpt, it said that maybe because my vectorbt(0.26.2) and numba(0.60.0) are not aligned , but when I downgrade numba to 0.57.0 it still doesn't work
